# How to fix dlib library installation error

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, dlib

I am working on a face recognition project on PyCharm. One of the requirements is to install dlib on PyCharm, however it keeps giving me the error prompt:

```
Collecting dlib
  Downloading dlib-19.24.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 3.2/3.2 MB 7.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib: started
  Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'

  DEPRECATION: dlib is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Running setup.py install for dlib did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [74 lines of output]
  running install
  C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
    warnings.warn(
  running build
  running build_py
  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
  
  running build_ext
  C:\Users\ardau\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hxmxtg3c\dlib_5bfb8e91737345edb848428a7f7e651a\setup.py:129: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
    if LooseVersion(cmake_version) < '3.1.0':
  Building extension for Python 3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\ardau\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hxmxtg3c\dlib_5bfb8e91737345edb848428a7f7e651a\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\ardau\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hxmxtg3c\dlib_5bfb8e91737345edb848428a7f7e651a\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\Scripts\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\ardau\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hxmxtg3c\dlib_5bfb8e91737345edb848428a7f7e651a\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):
  
  
  
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  
  
    You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
    are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
    that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
    development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.
  
  
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  
  
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\ardau\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hxmxtg3c\dlib_5bfb8e91737345edb848428a7f7e651a\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
      setup(
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1208, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 68, in run
      return orig.install.run(self)
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\install.py", line 698, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1208, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 132, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1208, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ardau\PycharmProjects\faceRecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\ardau\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hxmxtg3c\dlib_5bfb8e91737345edb848428a7f7e651a\setup.py", line 134, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\ardau\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hxmxtg3c\dlib_5bfb8e91737345edb848428a7f7e651a\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "C:\Users\ardau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\ardau\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hxmxtg3c\\dlib_5bfb8e91737345edb848428a7f7e651a\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\ardau\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hxmxtg3c\\dlib_5bfb8e91737345edb848428a7f7e651a\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\ardau\\PycharmProjects\\faceRecognition\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\ardau\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hxmxtg3c\\dlib_5bfb8e91737345edb848428a7f7e651a\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

Encountered error while trying to install package.

dlib

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I tried using an older version of python, however that did not work either. I made sure to install CMake however it is still not working. If anyone could help that would be great. I also made sure to install the necessary C/C++ extensions.

Comment: "You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++." -- so you installed that? Which version?

Comment: I installed the C/C++ extension from the vs code marketplace.

Comment: Where exactly do you see the error message say anything about some extensions for VSCode? You need Visual Studio (the real thing, not "Code"), either the full IDE with the C++ compiler, or just the standalone version. https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers